# Downloading large folders from Google Drive, but not entire folder

Tags: video, download, google-drive-file-stream

I've worked with the trashfire that is Google Drive for a decent bit now, and while initially the desktop app wasn't too painful to deal w/, as we were able to download and pick which folders to sync fully and which to ignore. However, ever since the recent change to Google Drive from Backup and Sync, the desktop app has made my workflow basically impossible. I've been trying to shift all of my files over from Google Drive out into different file hosting, and I have approximately 3TB of files to transfer over. I don't nearly have 3TB of space on my hard drive, so I'm doing this job over months trying to extract one major folder at a time, probably 1TB or so. The way I've been attempting to do this is to use the "stream files" mode and select the entire folder as available offline, which I assume is storing it on my hard drive. However, as I try to open these (video) files, they just aren't recognized, which I'm interpreting as having downloaded corrupted. When opening these files by downloading directly from the Drive website, these are absolutely fine, so I'm absolutely putting the blame on the software.

I'm looking for a way to download entire folders without this happening, so is there any alternative that doesn't use the cursed Google Drive software?

Comment: There exists third-party software (i.e., not Google) that will allow you to mount your Google Drive as a network share location.  That should be able to achieve what you want.  Questions seeking software recommendations are not within scope. Software Recommendations Stack Exchange does exist. *The software I suspect will work is paid software.* It would, in theory, allow you to transfer the files directly from one service to another, provided both services were supported by the third-party software.

Comment: Assumming that you are still open to give a chance to Google Drive for Desktop, please add more details like the name and version of the operative system that you are using, how do you verified that the file have completely download, the steps that followed to open the file and the textual error message.